# remove factors with criteria

Tags: r

I'm dealing with the KDD 2010 data https://pslcdatashop.web.cmu.edu/KDDCup/downloads.jsp
In R, how can I remove rows with a factor that has a low total number of instances.

I've tried the following:
create a table for the student name factor

```
studenttable <- table(data$Anon.Student.Id)
```

returns a table

```
l5eh0S53tB Qwq8d0du28 tyU2s0MBzm dvG32rxRzQ i8f2gg51r5 XL0eQIoG72 
  9890       7989       7665       7242       6928       6651
```

then I can get a table that tells me if there are more than 1000 data points for a given factor level

```
biginstances <- studenttable>1000
```

then I tried making a subset of the data on this query

```
bigdata <- subset(data, (biginstances[Anon.Student.Id]))
```

But I get weird subsets that still have the original number of factor levels as the full set.
I'm simply interested in removing the rows that have a factor that isn't well represented in the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I managed to do this.
I sorted the table of factors and associated counts.

```
studenttable <- sort(studenttable, decreasing=TRUE)
```

now that it's in order we could use column ranges sensibly. So I got the number of factors that are represented more than 1000 times in the data.

```
sum(studenttable>1000)
230
sum(studenttable<1000)
344
344+230=574
```

now we know the first 230 factor levels are the ones we care about. So, we can do

```
idx <- names(studenttable[1:230])
bigdata <- data[data$Anon.Student.Id %in% idx,]
```

we can verify it worked by doing

```
bigstudenttable <- table(bigdata$Anon.Student.Id)
```

to get a print out and see all the factor levels with less than 1000 instances are now 0.

Comment: That's pretty much how I would have done it. You may find, however, that if these are really factor variables that you may want to remove the extranous levels with `bigdata$Anon.Student.Id <- factor(bigdata$Anon.Student.Id)`

Comment: I just noticed that Manuel Ramon's answer  to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036700/removing-repeated-obs-data-if-n-obs-x-in-r would be a very succinct way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

There are probably more efficient ways to do this but this should get you what you want.  I didn't use the names you used but you should be able to follow the logic just fine (hopefully!)

```
# Create some fake data
dat <- data.frame(id = rep(letters[1:5], 1:5), y = rnorm(15))
# tabulate the id variable
tab <- table(dat$id)
# Get the names of the ids that we care about.
# In this case the ids that occur >= 3 times
idx <- names(tab)[tab >=3]
# Only look at the data that we care about
dat[dat$id %in% idx,]
```

Answer (score 4):

@Dason gave you some good code to work with as a starting point. I'm going to try to explain why (I think) what you tried didn't work.

```
biginstances <- studenttable>1000
```

This will create a logical vector whose length is equal the number of unique student id's. `studenttable` contained a count for each unique value of `data$Anon.Student.Id`. When you try to use that logical vector in `subset`:

```
bigdata <- subset(data, (biginstances[Anon.Student.Id]))
```

it's length is almost surely much less than the number of rows in `data`. And since the subsetting criteria in `subset` is meant to identify rows of `data`, R's recycling rules take over and you get 'weird' looking subsets.

I would also add that taking subsets to remove rare factor levels will *not change the levels attribute of the factor*. In other words, you'll get a factor back with no *instances* of that level, but all of the original factor levels will remain in the levels attribute. For example:

```
> fac <- factor(rep(letters[1:3],each = 3))
> fac
[1] a a a b b b c c c
Levels: a b c
> fac[-(1:3)]
[1] b b b c c c
Levels: a b c
> droplevels(fac[-(1:3)])
[1] b b b c c c
Levels: b c
```

So you'll want to use `droplevels` if you want to ensure that those levels are really 'gone'. Also, see `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach will involve a join between your dataset and the table of interest.
I'll use plyr for my purpose but it can be done using base function (like merge and as.data.frame.table)

```
require(plyr)

set.seed(123)
Data <- data.frame(var1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                   var2 = 1:100)


R> table(Data$var1)

 A  B  C  D  E 
19 20 21 22 18 


## rows with category less than 20

mytable <- count(Data, vars = "var1")

## mytable <- as.data.frame(table(Data$var1))

R> str(mytable)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var1: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ freq: int  19 20 21 22 18

Data <- join(Data, mytable)

## Data <- merge(Data, mytable)

R> str(Data)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ var1: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 3 2 3 5 3 5 5 4 3 1 ...
 $ var2: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ freq: int  21 20 21 18 21 18 18 22 21 19 ...



mysubset <- droplevels(subset(Data, freq > 20))

R> table(mysubset$var1)

 C  D 
21 22
```

Hope this help..