# Removing repeated obs data if n Obs < x in R

Tags: r, measures

I have a repeated measures data set. I need to remove all Participants where the number of observations for that individual is less than 3. What is the best way to do this?

```
x <- c(9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 23, 23, 23, 23, 45, 45, 45, 56, 56)
```

Here 11 and 56 need to be removed from the data.
So far I have created a data frame with all the obs that I want to keep but not sure how to manipulate my data set using the new data frame

```
x <- as.data.frame(table(x))
x1 <- x[x$Freq > 2,]
```

Comment: my data set is rather large (1000's obs) so this is taking rather a long time to run. Perhaps there is an alternative using a for loop or something? – user1033745 45 mins ago 
> raw.data1 <- raw.data[ave(raw.data$REGISTRA,raw.data,FUN=length) > 2] Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?) In addition:

Answer (score 4):

One more for the `ave()` function :

```
x[ave(x,x,FUN=length) > 2]
```

In an answer to your comment, you should perform it like this :

```
raw.data1 <- raw.data[ave(raw.data$REGISTRA,raw.data$REGISTRA,FUN=length) > 2]
```

Also read the help page of ave, that will help you understand what the code is doing exactly.

Comment: my data set is rather large (1000's obs) so this is taking rather a long time to run. Perhaps there is an alternative using a for loop or something?

Comment: > raw.data1 <- raw.data[ave(raw.data$REGISTRA,raw.data,FUN=length) > 2]
Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
In addition: >

Comment: A for loop isn't exactly an alternative for speed. Applying ave correctly would help too ;)

Comment: This is how I did it at first and it throws out warnings. > raw.data1 <- raw.data[ave(raw.data$REGISTRA,raw.data$REGISTRA,FUN=length) > 2]
Error in `[.data.frame`(raw.data, ave(raw.data$REGISTRA, raw.data$REGISTRA,  : 
  undefined columns selected
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 6L) : invalid factor level, NAs generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 6L) : invalid factor level, NAs generated
3

Comment: ahhh think it needs a comma before the ]

Comment: It is still throwing warnings... oh dear

Comment: 49: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 3L) : invalid factor level, NAs generated
50: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 4L) : invalid factor level, NAs generated
>

Comment: yeah, if you're running this on a factor, that might give trouble. Try `ave(as.numeric(raw.data$REGISTRA),raw.data$REGISTRA,FUN=Length) > 2`

Comment: That doesnt seem to be working either: Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'Length' not found
I guess because fun = Length needs to apply to a factor? hmmm

Comment: FUN=length, small l. it's because Length doesn't exist as a function.

Comment: corrected this and its still not giving me a useful data frame. It duplicates a load of variables but doesnt provide the frequency data. I think I will just use a for loop to iterate through and count each unique row for each unique id and add that to a column. Thanks for the help though, not sure why its not working.

Answer (score 4):

```
x[x %in% names(table(x)[table(x) >=3])]
```

Comment: This would also have answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023315/remove-factors-with-criteria, of course you would needed to have travel forward in time to know that it was going to be posted.

Comment: Less trouble with data conversion when working with factors. Nice

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023315/remove-factors-with-criteria was a perfect solution thanks!